# C# - How to send update value back to form class from a class where the work is done in a different thread

Tags: c#, multithreading

I'm working on a Splash/Loading screen for an app and I'd like to have a progress bar as well as a label on it which will notify the user of current process, e.g. connecting to the database, loading user settings, retrieving x data, retrieving y data.

I only did a tiny bit of BackGroundWorker stuff in VB before and nothing in C# so a bit confused where to start as it looks quite different in C#.

I'd like to keep the form class simple as to only calling specific methods from different classes on a different thread.

I mainly need to know how to update the GUI from the class that does the work as I think I could work out the threading itself from the below code:

```
    using System;
    using System.Threading;
    
    public class ThreadWork
    {
       public static void DoWork()
       {
          for(int i = 0; i<3;i++) {
             Console.WriteLine("Working thread...");
             Thread.Sleep(100);
          }
       }
    }

class ThreadTest
{
   public static void Main()
   {
      Thread thread1 = new Thread(ThreadWork.DoWork);
      thread1.Start();
      for (int i = 0; i<3; i++) {
         Console.WriteLine("In main.");
         Thread.Sleep(100);
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: why not use backgroundworker? it should be very similar if not the same in C# as vb.net

Comment: Oh dear... I didn't even think to check if backgroundworker exists in C#....

Comment: it does. It's the same! https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker?view=net-5.0

Comment: _"I didn't even think to check if backgroundworker exists in C#"_ ...if it's a .NET library (which it is) then it will be available for all .NET languages. That's one of the nice advantages of .NET - when you use a library like that, you're using the compiled code, not the source code, so the language it was originally written in (and the language you're using to interact with it) are irrelevant.

Comment: @MitchWheat I used your suggestion of using the background worker. Do you want to post it as an answer so I can mark it as the solution to this question?

Comment: @Pav. Perhaps you should post an answer yourself with your solution. All I did was mention it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the [`Task.Run`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.run) method to offload work to a `ThreadPool` thread, and a [`Progress<string>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.progress-1) object to report progress from the background thread to the UI. You can also use [async/await](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/async/) in order to write your code in a straightforward way. Here is an example:

```
private async void Form_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    IProgress<string> progress = new Progress<string>(message =>
    {
        Label1.Text = message;
    });

    var result = await Task.Run(() =>
    {
        progress.Report("Connecting to database...");
        ConnectToDatabase();
        progress.Report("Loading user settings...");
        LoadUserSettings();
        progress.Report("Retrieving x data...");
        return RetrieveXData();
    });

    // At this point the background processing has completed
    Label1.Text = $"Done! ({result})";
}
```

If you have heterogeneous data to report at different intervals, you can use multiple `Progress<T>` objects (for example a `Progress<string>`, a `Progress<int>` etc). You can also use a complex type for reporting, for example `Progress<(string, int)>`.

Answer (score 1):

Although Mitch's answer will work. You can also use TaskSchedulers to handle background work and then respond back to UI:

```
public static void Main()
        {
            TaskScheduler uiScheduler = TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext();
            Task.Factory.StartNew(() => DoBackgroundWork(uiScheduler));
        }

        private static void DoBackgroundWork(TaskScheduler uiScheduler)
        {
            // Do background stuff here...

            Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
            {
                // Respond back to UI here
                Console.WriteLine("Doing work");
                // Or if you have to change GUI, let's say a label value;
                label1.Text = "Text changed by background Task";

            }, CancellationToken.None, TaskCreationOptions.None, uiScheduler);
            
            // Some other background work
        }
```